# How to remove index.php with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I used next `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on
# if the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

It work nice, but it's available all pages with `index.php` and without it, for example:

```
http://localhost/framework/about
http://localhost/framework/index.php/about // need redirect to http://localhost/framework/about
```

I want to redirect all request with `index.php` to without `index.php` with SEO reasons, How can I remove `index.php`?

Comment: Where is your htaccess ? In your `framework` folder ?

Comment: You can use `ForceType` for this as well. It will allow you to drop the `.php` and does not require the `RewriteEngine`

Comment: @Tigger Can you show me example of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/([^/]+)/index\.php/(.+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

1. `%{THE_REQUEST}` contains the full HTTP request line sent by the
   browser to the server (e.g., `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`)
2. The condition `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/([^/]+)/index\.php/(.+)\s
   [NC]` matches something like `GET /xxx/index.php/yyyy` where **xxx** would be `framework` and **yyy** would be `about/something/what/you/want` or just `about` if you
   want (could be also `POST` or another instead of `GET` but it does not really matter here).

Example: `/framework/index.php/everything/about/me` will be redirected to `/framework/everything/about/me` or `/framework/index.php/about` will be redirected to `/framework/about`

Comment: Can you explain me `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/([^/]+)/index\.php/(.+)\s [NC]`, please? What is `%{THE_REQUEST}`? `%{REQUEST_URI}` is a same that `%{THE_REQUEST}`?

Comment: Sure. I edited my answer with an explanation for `%{THE_REQUEST}` and for the condition

Comment: I can't understand why you use `%1` and `%2` instead `$1` and `$2`? There are two different things?

Comment: Yes it's different: `%` when captured in `RewriteCond` and `$` when captured in `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the following will redirect everything to the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` var in `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.index.ph.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /index.php
```

It has been a while since I've used this method.

Alternatively you can use `ForceType` like this:

```
<Files *>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
<Files *\.*>
    ForceType None
</Files>
```

This will allow you to have a PHP file called `about` (no extension) and have it executed as PHP.